# quick file size check with PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

Is there a way to run a quick check what is the size of a file to be uploaded? I use a class that does it but I have to wait until it runs entirely before I can get that info. I would like to be able to skip going through the class if the file is larger, than say 5MB, i.e. don't even need it exactly if it is larger than max specified.

Thanks.

Comment: OK, I found a jQuery plug-in http://www.uploadify.com/demo/ If you take a look at the demo you'll see that it shows file size instantly, before it uploads the entire file. This is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. How is it accomplished?

Comment: it uses flash to validate file size initially i believe

Comment: if you really want to find out how fancyupload is done you can Github it https://github.com/digitarald/digitarald-fancyupload

Answer (score 1):

Yep. There's a variable in the $FILES tree called "size" see details here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Edit: also, you can set a max upload file size. You can set what php will accept, and put a hidden field in the html form to tell the browser what the max is (hopefully some browsers will do something intelligent with this.)

Comment: Thanks. $_FILES['userfile']['size'] gets the size of the uploaded file. Is there a way to perhaps estimate the size before uploading it? Because if it is larger than MAX I'd like to skip the entire upload process. What if someone decides to upload 100MB file and my max is 5MB...

Comment: PHP is server side. You asked how to check it with PHP. I hope that wasn't you who have me a thumbs down, when I answered exactly what you asked. Also, see my edit for how to tell the browser not to give you big files. I'm pretty sure (in most browsers anyway) there is no way for javascript to find out how big the file is. For security/privacy reasons, javascript isn't aloud to touch/see your files.

Comment: No it wasn't me. I'll give it +1 since you pointed me in the right direction even though my question was not correct.

Comment: Nope, no browser will do something intelligent with this field. It should be just avoided

Comment: @santa ok, thanks. @Col. Shrapmel: oh browsers! I have such expectations, but they're rarely met.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using JavaScript/Mootools with flash.

Here is a plugin that does exactly that.

[Fancyupload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/)

[Fancyupload Demo w/ image file upload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/3-0/showcase/single-file-button/)

Comment: This is cool. Is there anything similar for jQuery? I'd prefer to stick with just one library...

Comment: Please see my comment under initial question.

Comment: i did not know you were looking for jQuery, but php can not achieve this effect.

Answer (score 0):

you call it "uploaded" and misguide many people.

while you want to know filesize *before*  upload.

but before file gets entirely uploaded, **PHP isn't involved at all**

Comment: You're right. I corrected my question. Regardless, if it can't be done with PHP, can it be done at all? If with PHP, can I interrupt the process of upload and return some error message once the file reaches the MAX size?